# Prebind function in the ejabberd REST api

Tags: ejabberd

I have been looking for a function in the ejabberd REST admin api that provides prebind authentication for a given user, returning a jid, sid and rid. Having looked in the [documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/), I could find no such function. Does one exist?

Comment: If using ejabbered is not hard-requirement then you can use Tigase XMPP Server, which has this option https://docs.tigase.net/tigase-http-api/2.0.0/Tigase_HTTP-API_Guide/html/#boshPreBind

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like that. The closest thing is oauth_issue_token...